# uicontrol slider type min max sliderstep

Tags: matlab

I am trying to add a scrollbar (a slider) to a fixed-height figure.  There is a panel inside the figure and on the panel, there are multiple plots.  The panel is longer in Y direction than that of the figure so that the slider will be necessary to see the hidden plots.  I've created it and it is sort of working: showing the plots as the slider moves up and down.

The reason why I said "sort of" is because I couldn't understand the slider behavior with respect to its Min, Max, and SliderStep.

What I want to do is as follows:

1. Say I have 10 plots
2. The figure height allows only 6 to be shown (plot 1 through 6)
3. I want the slider size to be 6/10 of the figure height
4. So that it only takes one click (down arrow) to see the rest of the plots, but this time plots 5 through 10 will be shown

If I have 18 plots, then it should take two down-arrow clicks to see the last set of 6 figures and the slider size should be 1/3 of the figure height

I searched and searched for hours today, but I couldn't even find a good documentation on how to use Min and Max in conjunction with SliderStep.  All I could find was a comment that says "if you play enough with them, you'll get the size the way you want".  So, I played with them for another hours, but its behavior just doesn't make sense.

Comment: So you're talking about the size of the *bar* relative to the "track"?

Comment: @Suever, yes, thank you.  I didn't know the proper name of it.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the proper name, I just wanted to clarify what you meant.